# Small python Project

Tags: python

I am learning python and using Udacity website for it. In one of the projects, I need to make a program which enables users to take a break in every 2 hours. Now I understood the while function but it's showing an error called `expected a indent block`. Please help me to resolve it.
Here is my code:

```
 import webbrowser
    import time

    break_count=0
    total_count=3
    while(break_count<total_count):
    time.sleep(10)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlY5I1Lbe9c")
    break_count=break_count+1
```

What can I do to resolve the following issue?

Now i got the answer but i do not why i received negative votes as i really did not knew what was wrong with my code. Though i am thankful that i got an answer.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about error message? In Python indentation is part of syntax, so wrongly indented code won't behave as expected.

Comment: You have to indent the code inside your `while` loop, exactly as the error message said

Comment: Thankyou for your response. Actually i did not put space .. That is why i guess it was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Python does not have semicolons or brackets to show scope therefore this is shown by indentation (certain amount of spacing). You can use 4 spaces (tabs) or 2 spaces, just have your text editor settings changed. Everything should be inside your while loop indented. So I put the 3 lines below it inside the while loop assuming that is your intention.

```
import webbrowser
import time

break_count=0
total_count=3

while(break_count<total_count):
    time.sleep(10)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlY5I1Lbe9c")
    break_count=break_count+1
```

Comment: Technically Python does have semicolons, but their usage is optional

Comment: yeah .it worked... i just need to put space ..Thanks

Comment: Please don't use "4 spaces (tabs) or 2 spaces". Follow the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) and use 4 spaces. Always.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the code block that should run during your while loop:

```
import webbrowser
import time

break_count=0
total_count=3
while(break_count<total_count):
    #indent here
    time.sleep(10)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlY5I1Lbe9c")
    break_count=break_count+1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah i really did not knew that i need to give space(indent). I did searched it on many websites but i don't know why i was not able to resolve it.